# External sharing link settings

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-team-site, external-sharing

Can some help me understand why there's a difference in Link Settings while sharing Document vs Folder (screenshot below) while sharing it. My goal is to share Folder with a "Anyone..." link
External sharing setting at various level is

- Tenant Level ==> Anyone
- SharePoint Admin level ==> Anyone
- Site level ==> Anyone

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Please the following steps to enable external sharing link:**

**1. Set the Site sharing settings**

- Sign in the site as an admin
- Click **Site permissions** under the **Settings** menu
- On the Permissions panel, click the "**Change how members can share**" link

[image]

- On the Site sharing settings panel, select "**Site owners and members can share files, folders, and the site**" option

[image]

- **Save**

**2.Set the Site external sharing settings**

- Sign in the **SharePoint admin center** as SharePoint admin or Global admin
- Select **Sites** tab under the left navigation, and select **Active sites**

[image]

- Select the site that you want to share
- On the Site information panel, go to **Policies** tab and select **Edit** External sharing

[image]

- On the Sharing panel, select **Anyone** option under the **External sharing** section.

[image]

- **Save**

[image]

=======================**Updated Answer**==========================

**For public sites you only need to set the Site external sharing settings.**

- Sign in the **SharePoint admin center** as SharePoint admin or Global admin
- Select **Sites** tab under the left navigation, and select **Active sites**
- Select the site that you want to share

[image]

- On the Site information panel, go to **Policies** tab and select **Edit** External sharing

[image]

- On the Sharing panel, select **Anyone** option under the **External sharing**
  section.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please tell me what type does this screen shot belong to? I am trying to achive this is a (public) group connected team site

Comment: Hi, Akshay Randive. This is a Private site. For the operation of a Public site,  I have been updated answer under original My Answer.